# Javascript: while loop that operates by boolean value creates infinite loop

Tags: javascript

I have a while loop that works when I use a condition such as `while(x > 0)` however when I change it to `while(x == true)` or `while(x)` it turns into an infinite loop despite me having a condition that changes the variable to `false`.

Here's how that part of my code is set up.

```
let appendNums = ['8','2','8','14'], //for testing purposes
    carryCheck = true,
    incAmount  = 0;

incAmount = appendNums.length - 1;

while(carryCheck){
  let currentNum = appendNums[incAmount];

  if(currentNum.length > 1){
    let numSplitter = currentNum.split(''),
        equation    = Number(appendNums[incAmount - 1]) + Number(numSplitter[0]);

    appendNums[incAmount]     = numSplitter[1];
    appendNums[incAmount - 1] = equation.toString();
    incAmount                 = incAmount - 1;
  }
  else{ carryCheck = false; break; }
}
```

Overall what's happening, is I'm working on a function to do addition the way we've been taught to do it on paper in school with "carrying the one over".  I'm trying to tell the while loop to stop running when the `.length` of the current number is less than 2, indicating it's a single digit number and nothing else needs to be carried.  In this instance the `while(x > 0)` way of doing it wouldn't work because it keeps running beyond where I want it to stop.

I double checked the syntax on MDN and have come across a few posts on here where people made the mistake of doing `x = true` instead of `x == true` or `x === true`.  Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**
I just tried changing the while loop to `while(appendNums[incAmount] > 1)` and it still goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: why not just do `while (currentNum.length > 1)`?

Comment: It would be helpful if your code contained a [Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise we can't duplicate what you're seeing, because at the very least `ReferenceError: appendNums is not defined` (You're fine on the minimal part, it's just you're missing at least one thing to allow someone else to execute your code snippet)

Comment: ok I updated it, @Olian04, that doesn't work because `currentNum` isn't defined yet.  I define it inside the while loop.

Comment: Then why don't you define it outside the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

`Number(appendNums[incAmount - 1]) + Number(numSplitter[0])` will return `NaN` at some point because you do not check the array bounds.
By using `equation.toString()` and inserting it into `appendNums[incAmount -1]`, currentNum will always be the string `"NaN"` in the next iteration.
Since the string "NaN" has a length of 3, `currentNum.length > 1` will always be true.